# How come DBeaver fetch is very fast?

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, dbeaver

I am using DBeaver Version 22.3.1
Connected to Postgres 13

DBeaver 'select' query fetch is very fast (returning 200 rows - refresh on scroll)

[image]

When I run
`SELECT * FROM table_a;`

It is executed superfast. in 200ms on average. when total rows in table_a are 125mil+

but when I run
`SELECT count(*) FROM table_a;`

It takes about 23 sec for 125mil+ rows.

Does anyone know what DBeaver does for it to have such superfast result (granted gives only 200 rows, but still impressive)?

---

PS: Sorry I am not very good at databases, still learning. but every other question about DBeaver and performance was negative (like why is it slow) but IMHO it is very fast.

I am doubting it's not actually DBeaver but Database itself. <or is there some sort database/application integration magic involved?>

Executing following query:

`SELECT * FROM table_a LIMIT 200;`
is also quiet fast,

One more observation is it works very well with default ordering on primary key.
when sorted on another column (indexed or non indexed), the performance goes very bad.

Just want to have an opinion/confirmation from someone who is expert in database or DBeaver.

Thank you

Comment: Opinion based questions are off-topic on SO

Comment: I am sorry. where to ask this question then? Just want to have opinion of some expert. SO seems correct place for it. Thanks

Comment: Please have a look at [ask]. Consider having a look over at https://dba.stackexchange.com/ but read their tour first as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DBeaver limits the result set to 200 rows by default. That makes the first query fast, because it only has to read the first 200 rows. But the query that counts the rows has to fetch them all, so it takes much longer.

Moreover, the row limit of 200 actually slows down counting: without the row limit, PostgreSQL would use parallel workers to count the rows and be somewhat faster. But with the row limit, PostgreSQL does not use parallel query, because PostgreSQL cannot be certain that it can stop parallel processing after 200 result rows. So you get some overhead for the parallel infrastructure, and yet the query will run single-threaded.

Remove the row limit of 200, and everything will work as you would expect it.

See [this article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/parallel-query-postgresql-problems-jdbc-dbeaver/) for details.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That is a great article explaining limitations of fixedrowsize in dbeaver on parallelism and how to solve it. But I don't think there is any kind of parallelism enabled on the db i am using, as every "explain analyze" on any table gives "Seq Scan" not "Parallel scan". Great read tho. Thank you. PS: I was working on improving performance of one of the application. and was wondering how dbeaver does this superfast, and if I will be able to use it in my application. That article does give me some hope. Thanks again. Will look more into this new lead :)

Comment: Hm, with a normal configuration, a `count(*)` on a large table will use a parallel sequential or index scan. But that was just an aside: I thought my answer made clear why `SELECT *` is fast: see the `200 row(s) fetched` in your image.